# iOS custom footer view issue in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, viewcontroller

I am trying to make the footer view for the `UITableView` but I am these facing issues

1. First of all I do not know How to make footer view for `UITableView`. I
   know that I can make design separately in Nib. So I did that. Now I
   do not know How to load that footer as `UITableView` sticky footer.
2. My Footer will have 2 sub views & these views are `TextField` & `Button`
3. By Having `TextField` in footer will be problem as keyboard will cover up them and user will unable to see what he is typing.

Please tell me how can I do that???

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this datasource to show footer -> [tableView(_:viewForFooterInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614946-tableview)
2. First create your design a/c to your requirement & return to the above mentioned delegate.
3. To rid of this issue, you can use [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager). It automatically manages your layout for keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let footerView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FooterView") as! FooterTableViewCell

    return footerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```